# Change where in elf file code execution starts

Tags: elf

I want to change where in the elf file execution starts. For example I have a basic hello world program in a elf file. The actual code is located at an offset of 0x1000 bytes into the file. I want to move that code to, lets say, a 0x900 offset and modify the file so that it starts executing at 0x900. I know this sounds kinda useless but it does serve a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First you compile/assemble (clang/as/...) your program into a *hello.o* ELF object file. At this point, you would normally let the compiler driver finish the job and emit an ELF executable.

You can instead use the linker (lld/ld/...) and specify the entry point with *--entry 0x900*. You can also do this with a linker script. Note that if you do this, you have to handle a bunch of stuff that the compiler driver normally handles for you. The warning from the Oracle linker manual says:

> When you invoke the link-editor directly, you have to supply every
> object file and library required to create the intended output. The
> link-editor makes no assumptions about the object modules or libraries
> that you meant to use in creating the output.